# Keyboard Shortcut for formatting posts on Mac should support ⌘

Tags: discussion, feature-request

The keyboard shortcuts for **bold** and *italics* on SO et al is incorrectly implemented on Mac, IMHO.

On Mac, we use the <kbd>⌘</kbd> key to invoke keyboard shortcuts. However, on SO, I have to remember to use <kbd>control</kbd>.

Can we get the <kbd>⌘</kbd> for keyboard shortcuts implemented please?

Comment: I am upvoting you now... **not because I think we need this support**, but, because **the support is inconsistent across browsers** :-)

Comment: Seems to be `[status-completed]`, at least in current versions of Safari? (And some [don't like that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100349/on-mac-based-browser-command-l-should-select-the-address-bar)...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: nowadays, in Safari 5.1 on OS X 10.6, all keys seem to work for both Ctrl and Command, including Command-B and Command-I. I guess an update on Safari has fixed this; on an OS X 10.5 Safari 5.0.5  still showed the old behaviour, but not after I now updated it to 5.0.6.

---

Oddly enough, in Safari: Command-L does work (*a tiny bit* annoying, as I'm used to that to go into the location bar, but that's not happening a lot when I've started typing something). And so do Command-Q and Command-H (more annoying, as those are Quit and Hide on a Mac). Also: Command-G, Command-K, Command-O and others.

But, in Safari: <s>not so much for bold and italic.</s>

So: maybe Safari is only listening to keys that normally have some other meaning, and ignoring anything that Safari does not know about? If true, then map Command-B and Command-I to some of Safari's menu items, and you're settled.

Comment: To clarify off-hand, there was a WebKit bug that prevented `Command + B`, `Command + I`, and `Command + A` events from being raised in certain scenarios, because Safari was trying to use them for its own formatting shortcuts. To my knowledge, this was fixed sometime last year, but it seems that maybe the changes weren't pulled into Safari  until recently.

Answer (score 7):

No, no, no, no, ***no***!

This web app should *not* be hijacking my <kbd>⌘</kbd> key! That key is for commands sent to the *native* application, in which a website happens to be displayed. You want <kbd>⌘-Q</kbd> to be "blockquote"? <kbd>⌘-O</kbd> to start a list? These key combinations have established meanings for which I (and plenty of other users) have decades of muscle memory. It's bad enough <kbd>Control-B</kbd> (emacs for "move back a character", which you can use in text editing on Mac OS X) gets commandeered for "mark up bold text". There's no way a web app should be changing the fundamental key bindings of my OS.

Stay off my <strike>lawn</strike> keyboard!

Answer (score 5):

I hate Command+R is bound to insert ruler in editor window because it overrides refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked: both versions work in Chrome, with cmd and control.

Kudos to SO team, very considerate.

Comment: Not by me... Incidentally, I can't seem to copy in chat either.

Comment: @Moshe What browser?

Comment: @Moshe that's a separate issue

Comment: @NikitaRybak - Safari 5 on 10.6.6

Comment: I can confirm it does not work in Safari.

Comment: And that it does in Chrome. Okay... strange.

Answer (score 0):

This will be very difficult to implement because [detecting the Command key on Mac OS using JavaScript is done very differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-to-capture-macs-command-key-via-javascript). I don't think it's worth it.

Also, it's likely that the OS will capture Command-key equivalents before the application does. It's very rare to be able to use <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Any</kbd> key combination on websites. I don't think most users will expect it.

Besides, should you just be writing markdown? :-)

**EDIT:** I can confirm this *does* work in Chrome for Mac... Meaning I change my position. This should be fixed to be made uniform. Either support it uniformly, or don't.

Comment: I actually find that most websites support ⌘ vis-a-vis the browser itself, as opposed to built in editors.