# How to delete one line with the SO editor?

Tags: support, edits, osx

I'm using Mac, and the good thing about it is that the emacs key is mapped so that I can use 'Ctrl-A' for going first column line, and 'Ctrl-E' for last and on.

The thing is that for 'Ctrl-K', it doesn't delete one line, instead it makes code format for the current line.

- What's the command for deleting one line in the SO editor?
- Can I reassign the key by any way? I guess it's not possible, but I just ask.

Answer (score 2):

The markdown editor doesn't have a "delete line" key.

You just have to select the line and press <kbd>Delete</kbd>. Or <kbd>Del</kbd>, if your keyboard swings that way.

Answer (score 2):

I am also frustrated by the way StackOverflow attaches itself to keyboard shortcuts that Mac would ordinarily use. For example I am in Safari right now. If I decide I want to give up on this post and quit Safari, I type <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>.

> Oh wait... what's this? Why am I in a blockquote now? No JavaSCript should be able to override a Command-Q (Quit) keyboard action!

Looks like it's affecting the Emacs-style line editing built into OS X also. I think the best solution here is a userscript... (unless the team is wiling to fix it, which I think they have said they are not)

If a userscript is possible, I'm not sure. I'll investigate and update my answer.

Comment: As an aside: it seems that in Safari the editor only binds to Command shortcuts that were already known for other usage. Like indeed Command-Q and Command-L. But not Command-B and Command-I for bold and italic. (But they are mapped in Chrome and Firefox. But in all browsers on a Mac, Ctrl-B and Ctrl-I work just fine too. No need for also mapping Command at all, for me. [Keyboard Shortcut for formatting posts on Mac should support ⌘](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78599/keyboard-shortcut-for-formatting-posts-on-mac-should-support) — or should it?)

Comment: And, of course, the real life example is the Boss Button, Command-H ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Arjan I knew I had discussed this somewhere before quite recently