# Stack Overflow editor shortcut "overrides" the Safari shortcut

Tags: discussion, keyboard-shortcuts, safari, osx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On Mac browsers, Command-L should select the address bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100349/on-mac-browsers-command-l-should-select-the-address-bar)

I often use `CMD + H` for hiding Safari (or any other application on the Mac). However, while I am editing a post in Stack Overflow I can't use this shortcut because `CMD + H` adds a new markdown-header within the editor window. So instead of hiding, it inserts the following

```
## Heading ##
```

I personally don't think that a website should cancel out a browser's or the operating system's  shortcuts in any case.

Comment: I'm personally annoyed by the `^I` feature. That's how I ask my browser to spawn an external editor on the text area; Matthew's suggestion of defocussing the text area first can't work for that. :(

Comment: Same for **Ctrl+K**. Very annoying.

Answer (score 2):

The website is given the power by the browser which is given the power by the OS.  The website is not cancelling out or overriding the shortcut, it's simply providing a feature.

Shortcuts are more or less arbitrary, and limited to common things (like CMD+H) if they want to be memorable and easy to use.  There's no way to avoid collision, especially with all the browser/OS/other combinations out there.  (I use CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+C for the calculator in Windows ... guess what that does in Chrome?)

The habit of clicking or tabbing out of the box before minimizing shouldn't be hard to pick up.