# I would like to be able to use the default functionality for Ctrl + h

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

On OSX, in 90% of use-cases, `Ctrl + h` is the same as hitting the backspace button (with the added efficiency of not needing to move my hand off of home-row). I've grown so accustom to using it, that it has become muscle memory and the override on StackExchange is constantly throwing me off.

For those of you who don't know, while writing a question or an answer on SE, `Ctrl + h` will try to create a header by adding this: ## Heading ##

As you can imagine, this is an incredibly frustrating experience for users who expect the last character written to be deleted. Is there a reason this keyboard shortcut override makes sense?

I would like to submit a feature request to remove it, or possibly add some sort of configuration so an arbitrary user could turn it off.

Comment: If it is only removed, you'll be frustrating me.

Comment: Closely related: [Is there a way to disable the hotkeys?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2980) See also: [On Mac browsers, command-L should select the address bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100349) and (on MSO, updated userscript) [How can I disable the keyboard shortcuts in the Stack Overflow editor?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318983)

Comment: Since when is `Ctrl` + `H` an OS X shortcut for back? I can't get it to do anything. What browser are you using? I'm pretty sure `Cmd` + `[` is the true back shortcut.

Comment: Oh, you can also use `Cmd` + `H` in the editor.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara It's the backspace shortcut (sorry for the ambiguity, i'll update my answer) - it's not browser specific, it works everywhere, including textedit, you just have to be typing in a field.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara It looks like `Cmd + h` in the editor also adds `## Heading ##`, which I would argue is more of a reason to remove the override from `Ctrl + h` - there is already a shortcut key to add a header.

Comment: Oh, I see. The editors I tried that in did not behave this way. It should be possible to disable this for only `Ctrl` + `h` and leave `Cmd` + `h`.